# Samba bug, need help running a command at boot to fix it

Tags: server, samba

I have [this bug](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11647) in the latest Samba available in the Ubuntu 15.10 repository. As Sylvain Pasche says, you can work around it by doing the following:

```
mkdir /mnt/root
mount -o rbind / /mnt/root
```

The problem is, once I reboot, the shares show as empty, and I have to manually run

```
mount -o rbind / /mnt/root
```

So that `~/` is visible again. Can someone tell me how to do that, or how to update Samba past 4.1.7 on Ubuntu 15.10 so that I can be move past this bug? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create another startup script that runs before the samba startup (lower number) that executes that mount command.  Or you can edit your existing samba startup script to add that mount command at the top, and then verifying its existence before proceeding on with the samba startup.

Comment: Im sorry, can you explain?  A) how do I create a startup script that has B) a lower number?